# R ggplot transparency - alpha values conditional on other variable

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data: [example from R graphics Cookbook]

```
Cultivar Date Weight sd          n  se          big
c39     d16   3.18  0.9566144   10  0.30250803  TRUE
c39     d20   2.8   0.2788867   10  0.08819171  TRUE
c39     d21   2.74  0.9834181   10  0.3109841   TRUE
c52     d16   2.26  0.4452215   10  0.14079141  FALSE
c52     d20   3.11  0.7908505   10  0.25008887  TRUE
c52     d21   1.47  0.2110819   10  0.06674995  FALSE
```

I would like to have a bar plot where bar transparency depends on `big` variable.

I have tried the following, where I tried to set `alpha` values depending on different `big` values:

```
ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x=Date, y=Weight, fill=Cultivar)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x=Date, y=Weight, fill=Cultivar)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", alpha=cabbage_exp$big=c("TRUE"= 0.9, "FALSE" = 0.35)) 
ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x=Date, y=Weight, fill=Cultivar)) +
 geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", alpha=big=c("TRUE"= 0.9, "FALSE" = 0.35))
```

I would like to have different transparency in the bars depending on the value of the big variable. Any help or guidance hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Another possibility using `scale_alpha_discrete`, where the `range` argument may be used to set your desired `alpha` values for each level of 'big'.

```
ggplot(data = cabbage_exp, aes(x = Date, y = Weight, fill = Cultivar, alpha = big)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.35, 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a better solution, at least there is a correct legend and no need to compute alpha values beforehand.

Comment: This is also an excellent solution when you want to show line trends only for specific levels on a bar plot! (essentially plotting partial data on geom_line and full data on geom_bar) Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 15):

The problem here is that your variable is discrete, whereas the `alpha` scale is continuous. One way to do it is to manually compute your alpha values before plotting :

```
alpha <- ifelse(d$big, 0.9, 0.35)
ggplot(d, aes(x=Date, y=Weight, fill=Cultivar)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", aes(alpha=alpha))
```

The downside is that you won't get a correct legend for your alpha values. You can delete it with this :

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=Date, y=Weight, fill=Cultivar)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", aes(alpha=big)) +
    scale_alpha_continuous(guide=FALSE)
```

Final result :

[image]