# Colors in grouped boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, grouped-bar-chart

I am creating grouped boxplots for a stratified sample using ggplot. As a made up example, on the y-axis is the value (say, test scores) and on the x-axis are the categories (White, Black, and Asian. But I also am gruoping eaching category by another variable (say, male vs. female). So, there will be 6 boxes.

I want the categories to have the colors red, blue, and purple. But I want the sex grouping variable to make the colors light and dark (e.g., male asian = light purple and female asians = dark purple).

Is this possible? Thanks!

I have searched pretty extensively online and not found a solution. I am sure I can't be the first person doing this, but I haven't found an explanation for how to do this yet.

Comment: A common way to do this is to map `sex` to the `alpha` aesthetic, which controls transparency. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24800626/903061).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that from a data visualisation perspective, there is no reason to color each group on the x axis a different color: they are already clearly labelled, so this is unnecessary embellishment that ultimately makes the plot more difficult for the viewer to parse, purely for the "eye candy" effect of color.

Comment: Check this gallery as well https://r-graph-gallery.com/boxplot.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. You could use the `alpha` aesthetic:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Race, Score, fill = Race, alpha = Sex,, 
               group = interaction(Sex, Race))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge(0.1), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("deepskyblue", "purple", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "gray"))) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or fill by the `interaction` of Sex and Race

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Race, Score, fill = interaction(Sex, Race, sep = " "), 
               group = interaction(Sex, Race))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.7, outlier.colour = NA) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge(0.1), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("deepskyblue3", "deepskyblue",
                                     "purple3", "purple",
                                     "red3", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Personally, I find this use of color gratuitous and confusing. When presenting data, color should be used to clearly identify groupings, but there is no need to do this if the grouping are already apparent on the axis. I think the following is cleaner, classier and easier to understand at a glance (as well as being colorblind safe)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Race, Score, fill = Sex, group = interaction(Sex, Race))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, outlier.colour = NA, width = 0.3,
               position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge(0.05, 0, 0.5), 
             alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("gold", "deepskyblue4")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "top")
```

[image]